# Visual Studio Code toolbars

Tags: visual-studio-code

Ok, so in a previous question I had a problem downloading Visual Studio in which I was able to do so after a ton of research. However, I am having a problem running the programs I write such as a simple Hello World app. I can get it to run through the terminal by typing "dotnet run", but the problem is, no external window appears that shows what it is supposed to say.

[image]

I am trying to follow along with a video tutorial for school and in the video, I noticed that the guy has a Start button at the top.

[image]

However, all I have available is File, Edit, Selection, View, Go, Run, Terminal, and Help.

[image]

The run button when pushed on other IDEs will do what I described earlier, however, with this one I get a huge drop-down with multiple choices (such as .NET 5+ and .NET Core) on which aspect I want to use to run, the choices that look C# friendly I choose only for nothing to happen. I have tried searching for the answer as to why I do not have that particular toolbar and the suggestions are to go to tools, I went through all of the given menu items and there is no tools section. So, I am at a loss. Again, I am using Visual Studio Code, and I am also on a Linux Manjaro which means I cannot get any other version of Visual Studio as far as I can tell at this moment.

How do I get the Start button???

Comment: The toolbar in the video is the one from the full Visual Studio IDE.    "Start Debugging" under the Run menu of Visual Studio Code is the equivalent.  No external windows will open with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: When I hit start debugging, I get a drop-down and usually choose the .NET option but nothing happens. I checked all boxes such as Problems, Output, Console, and Terminal, nothing appears in any of those boxes after my selection. The only way I can even get it to do anything at all is by using "dotnet run" in Terminal. I am sad to hear that I cannot see my programs in full fruition. I hope they add even if is just that to the IDE in the near future.

Comment: Try setting some breakpoints.  I don't have VS Code set up for .NET, so I don't know the ins and outs of the debugger.

Comment: The breakpoints do not bring up any windows. I am just going to have to wait until I learn more to be able to make .exe files. Until then, I will have to trust that if no error codes come out, then the code is good. It is an uneasy feeling to rely on what the IDE is telling me without any visualization.

Comment: VSC has a doc page on C#